# Ethereumjs putContractStorage throws an error

Tags: evm, ethereumjs, storage, ethereumjs-tx, storage-trie

I'm experimenting with Ethereumjs and having issues with the `putContractStorage` from `vm.stateManager`.

The following code snippet:

```js
const { VM } = require('@ethereumjs/vm')

const vm1 = new VM()
const vm2 = new VM()

; (async () => {
    
    // deploy contract
    const signedTx = '...'
    const result = await vm1.runTx({ tx: signedTx, skipBalance: true })
    
    // assign account to vm2
    const account = await vm1.stateManager.getAccount(result.createdAddress)
    await vm2.stateManager.putAccount(result.createdAddress, account)

    // assign storage to vm2
    const contractStorage = await vm1.stateManager.dumpStorage(result.createdAddress)
    const [[k, v]] = Object.entries(contractStorage)
    const key = new Uint8Array(Buffer.from(k.substring(2), 'hex'))
    const value = new Uint8Array(Buffer.from(v.substring(2), 'hex'))
    await vm2.stateManager.putContractStorage(result.createdAddress, key, value) // throws error

})()
```

Throws this error:

```sh
./node_modules/@ethereumjs/trie/dist/cjs/trie.js:362
            throw new Error('Stack underflow');
                  ^

Error: Stack underflow
    at Trie._updateNode (./node_modules/@ethereumjs/trie/dist/cjs/trie.js:362:19)
    at Trie.put (./node_modules/@ethereumjs/trie/dist/cjs/trie.js:170:24)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async ./node_modules/@ethereumjs/statemanager/dist/cjs/stateManager.js:295:17
```

One thing that seem off is the `account` variable from the snippet above. The `account` variable contains a `storageRoot` field that maybe should be reassigned to the `storageRoot` of the new vm.

Reproducible example on https://github.com/LiveDuo/ethereumjs-putstorage-issue.

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed the `storageRoot`.

To fix the code snippet above:

```js
...
// assign account to vm2
const account = await vm1.stateManager.getAccount(result.createdAddress)
const accountFixed = new Account(BigInt(account.nonce), BigInt(account.balance))
await vm2.stateManager.putAccount(result.createdAddress, accountFixed)
...
```